# Why is the `vimscript` tag aliased simply to `vim`?

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

Writing **VimL**, as a programmer is a very different topic than *using* **Vim**, as a programmer. Having non-VimL-related Vim questions on StackOverflow [has been discussed previously](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25925/vim-questions-do-they-belong-to-stack-overflow-or-super-user); and the verdict seems to be ‘questions about using Vim are welcome on StackOverflow.’

If this is the case, then I posit that the [vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vim) tag should be used for *usage* questions, and the [viml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/viml) tag for *scripting* (programming Vim) questions actually related to, well, VimL / `.vimrc` / &c. Currently, however, the latter (or, well, the [vimscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vimscript) tag … see below.) is synonym'd to the former.

Thoughts?

---

On a small side-note, [there's some disagreement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398312/vimscript-or-viml/31422313#31422313) about the proper name for “the embedded programming language with which one can script Vim.” To summarize, “Vim script” (note the capitalization) is what it is consistently called within Vim's documentation; but that is a notoriously difficult phrase to search. Meanwhile, GitHub [chose to call](https://github.com/search?l=VimL&q=language:VimL) the language ‘VimL’, for probably precisely that reason.

I'm ambivalent as to whether the tag should be [vimscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vimscript) or [viml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/viml); I suggest the latter, but as long as one is aliased to the other, I don't think that's as big a deal.

Comment: (Aside: I added [a tag-wiki entry](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/viml/info) for **`viml`**, pending a discussion here of whether the splitting is a good idea.)

Answer (score 10):

(I was one of the people that voted to accept the synonym.)

(Going off of memory) At the time that the [vimscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vimscript) to [vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vim) alias was suggested, there were about 1k questions tagged vimscript and about 10k tagged [vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vim). However 99.9% of the questions tagged vimscript were also tagged vim. At one point I looked at the newest 50 questions in the vimscript tag and all of them were also tagged vim.

Also if the question wasn't tagged vim, the question most likely fell through the cracks and never got answered.

Comment: Is it a huge issue if it's tagged both? The point would be for an experienced person to follow the `VimL` tag (which is a desperately needed thing: VimL is extremely confusing sometimes, and it's something it looks like people come here for help with fairly often~) and answer questions on that specific topic, as opposed to vim-usage. If they show up for general searches for `vim`, too, all the better … no?

Comment: (Just checking on policy and whatnot: this is my first post to meta, so.)

Comment: @ELLIOTTCABLE Probably not. However since you are only allowed to add 5 tags to a question, having a tag that conveys no new information isn't helpful. For instance the regex tag needs to be paired with another tag since there are a million dialects for regex. vim regex is pretty strange. So now you have regex, vim and vimscript. If you got to the limit the first tag to be removed would probably be the vimscript tag since the vim tag conveys all the necessary information.

Comment: @ELLIOTTCABLE As for who follows vimscript/viml and who follows vim. I believe that the people that follow vimscript will be a strict subset of the people that follow vim. I don't remember if I followed the vimscript tag when it was around, however I know that I don't follow the [tag:vim-plugin] tag. If you look at that tag you would see that the behavior that was similar to the vimscript tag when it existed. I would say that technically it allows more book keeping but I'm not really sure how much more. (Also there is a dedicated site at vi.stackexchange.com, if you want to go crazy with tags)

Answer (score 4):

I agree with FDinoff in their answer that [vimscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vimscript) is very meta as a tag.

Point: While there are good stances on keeping VimL questions as its own field, it tends to be consistently misused.

Proposition: Perhaps they can be kept separate (and not synonymized) and a developer can add a warning to use only one when the question asker tries to use both tags.

Side note: Depending on the effect of the mistagging in [vimscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vimscript), a demand for a [retag-request](/questions/tagged/retag-request) may commence.

Comment: When you say ‘a developer’ … does that mean new implementation work? or is that already a feature, like synonyms, that can be easily enabled for a tag such as this? Doesn't seem worth the effort if the former.